# The cursor grab option is not working in Internet Explorer using CSS

Tags: css, internet-explorer

For dragging the div I need to use cursor grab option. But it is not working in Internet Explorer. I tried to use cursor with url option. That is also not working in Internet Explorer. Is there any way to change the cursor design?

Comment: Grab option will work only for firefox and webkit. 

    .grabbable {
        cursor: move; /* fallback if grab cursor is unsupported */
        cursor: grab;
        cursor: -moz-grab;
        cursor: -webkit-grab;
    }
    
    If we want it in ie, we have to set the cursor image as follows. Only cur or ani file extensions will work in ie.
    
    .grabbable {
        cursor: url(images/my-cursor.cur), auto;
    }

Answer (score 19):

You can download the cursors used by Gmail. Download [this one](http://ssl.gstatic.com/ui/v1/icons/mail/images/2/openhand.cur) and save it as "grab.cur" and [this one](http://ssl.gstatic.com/ui/v1/icons/mail/images/2/closedhand.cur) and save it as "grabbing.cur" in the same folder as your HTML document. Then insert the following codes in you HTML document according to if you want the grab cursor or the grabbing cursor:

- Grab cursor: `style="cursor: url(grab.cur), move"`
- Grabbing cursor: `style="cursor: url(grabbing.cur), move"`

Comment: Or just take the ones used by Gmail: http://ssl.gstatic.com/ui/v1/icons/mail/images/2/openhand.cur and http://ssl.gstatic.com/ui/v1/icons/mail/images/2/closedhand.cur

Comment: For those who are wondering why their code doesn't work, a fallback part `, move` is required and it must be present inside the same rule like stated above. Fallback on a separate rule won't help. Also, the URL to cursor must be absolute or relative to the document, not the CSS file, unlike all other files (images, fonts, etc). I believe only FF is able to understand CSS-relative paths for cursors.